# How to solve RenderMode OpenGL

Tags: android

Trying to change the default RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY to RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY so my app won't start displaying the graphics until a button is pressed.  So far the app just crashes when implementing the Render Mode.

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    openGLView = (OpenGLView) findViewById(R.id.openGLView);
    openGLView = new OpenGLView(this);
    openGLView.setRenderer((GLSurfaceView.Renderer) openGLView);
    openGLView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    buttonclick();
}
```

### Edit:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.boss.fascist, PID: 29999
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.boss.fascist/com.boss.fascist.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.boss.fascist.OpenGLView cannot be cast to android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$Renderer
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2972)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3051)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1701)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6797)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:772)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.boss.fascist.OpenGLView cannot be cast to android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$Renderer
        at com.boss.fascist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6989)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2925)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3051) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1701) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6797) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:772) 
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite not found.
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:11140
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 11140
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:5
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 5
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite not found.
I/Ads: App measurement is starting up, version: 14711
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
Application terminated.
```

Comment: Please, add the stack trace.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.boss.fascist/com.boss.fascist.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.boss.fascist.OpenGLView cannot be cast to android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$Renderer

Comment: This seems to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are casting 2 noncompatible objects -> **(GLSurfaceView.Renderer) openGLView**

Also, don't attribute a new instance right after attributing through findViewById, this is useless.

```
openGLView = (OpenGLView) findViewById(R.id.openGLView);
openGLView = new OpenGLView(this);
```

Comment: If openGLView is my openGLS code.  How would I make it so that Rendermode would be correctly cast?  So that the backround wouldn't immediately start the blinking animation.  Thanks for the help!